# Phaser P2 Sprite Scale Change not working properly for all group children

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

I hope this code explains what I'm trying to do. I have a pool table, and I want the balls to accelerate into the pockets if they are close enough. At this point I'm not yet checking the distance, just working to figure out how to do it.

I'm sure there is a better way!

```
  balls.forEachAlive(
    pockets.forEachAlive( moveBallTowardPocket, this), this);
```

Update: The following code is working except one thing, the scale change for balls on the first five pockets.  Acceleration is working for all balls to all pockets.  Scale change is only working on the last pocket, not the first five.

```
function update() {
  pockets.forEachAlive(function(pocket) {
    accelerateBallToPocket(flipper, pocket, 60);
    balls.forEachAlive(function(ball) {
      accelerateBallToPocket(ball, pocket, 60);
    });
  });
  //...
}

function accelerateBallToPocket(ball, pocket, speed) {
  if (typeof speed === 'undefined') {
    var speed = 120;
  }
  var pocket_body_x = pocket.body.x;
  var pocket_body_y = pocket.body.y;
  var ball_body_x   = ball.body.x;
  var ball_body_y   = ball.body.y;

  // move ball toward pocket if close enough
  var dx = ball_body_x - pocket_body_x;  //distance ship X to enemy X
  var dy = ball_body_y - pocket_body_y;  //distance ship Y to enemy Y
  var dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);   //pythagoras

  if (dist < pocket_radius * pocket_leniency_factor) {

    // accelerate ball to pocket on right angle
    var angle = Math.atan2(pocket.y - ball.y,
                             pocket.x - ball.x);
    ball.body.rotation = angle + game.math.degToRad(90);
    ball.body.force.x = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
    ball.body.force.y = Math.sin(angle) * speed;

    // change scale
    // FIXME only works on the last pocket lower right
    if (ball === flipper) {
      ball.scale.setTo(Math.tan(pocket.x - ball.x),
                         Math.tan(pocket.y - ball.y));
    } else {
      ball.scale.setTo(Math.sin(pocket.x - ball.x),
                         Math.cos(pocket.y - ball.y));
    }
  } else {
    // reset the scale when the ball is out of range of the pocket
    ball.scale.setTo(1.0, 1.0);
  }
}
```

2nd Update:
The following, based on the solution, has me going in the right direction again, I think...

```
  for (var i = 0; i < pockets.children.length; i++) {
    accelerateBallToPocket(cue, pockets.children[i], 60);
    if (cue.pocketing) break;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < balls.children.length; i++) {
    if (balls.children[i].pocketing) continue;
    for (var j = 0; j < pockets.children.length; j++) {
      accelerateBallToPocket(balls.children[i], pockets.children[j], 60);
      if (balls.children[i].pocketing) return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the scale supposed to do (I mean, what should the user see) ?

Comment: When any of the balls (or the flipper ball) get close enough to the pockets, the scale of the ball changes using the trig functions, so the ball appears to spasm. It's working on one pocket, but not the others.

Comment: @Tibe Lake What is the flipper ball? First time I hear this term in pool. Maybe you need to `abs` the `X` and `Y` distances between the ball and the pockets.

Comment: I was making a pinball game but it turned into pool. I just haven't renamed it yet, but it's the same body type as the other balls, but in a different group. Please note the function is working for all features except scaling on the first five pockets.  So the distance metric is working.

Comment: Yes, but when you change the scale you use this distance: `pocket.x - ball.x` which has a different sign based on the relative position between the ball and the pocket. I'm not saying that this is the issue, but this certainly makes the "spasm" act different based on which corner the pocket is.

Comment: I've changes the scaling lines to: `ball.scale.setTo(Math.sin(dist), Math.tan(dist));` but I still get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that you set the scale to 1 if the ball isn't close to a pocket. And, as you check each ball against each pocket, there will always be one pocket (that is checked later in the loop) that the ball is not close too, except the last pocket in the pocket list. So, even if the ball scale is set to the correct value, it will be reset when the next `pocket` is being checked.

What you can do is check whether a ball is close to at least one pocket, if it is then it can't be close the the other pockets so you don't check again agaist the other pockets.

```
// Consider that every ball is not inside a pocket
balls.forEachAlive(function(ball) {
   ball.inPocket = false;
});
flipper.inPocket = false; // You should really add the flipper to the balls group to remove duplicate code

pockets.forEachAlive(function(pocket) {
    if(!flipper.inPocket) accelerateBallToPocket(flipper, pocket, 60);
    balls.forEachAlive(function(ball) {
      if(!ball.inPocket) accelerateBallToPocket(ball, pocket, 60);
    });
  });
```

Then, in your move function you have to set the `inPocket` member to true if a ball is close to the pocket.

```
function accelerateBallToPocket(ball, pocket, speed) {

    ...

    if (ball === flipper) {
      ball.scale.setTo(Math.tan(pocket.x - ball.x),
                         Math.tan(pocket.y - ball.y));
      ball.inPocket = true;
    } else {
      ball.scale.setTo(Math.sin(pocket.x - ball.x),
                         Math.cos(pocket.y - ball.y));
      ball.inPocket = true;
    }
  } else {
    // reset the scale when the ball is out of range of the pocket
    ball.scale.setTo(1.0, 1.0);
  }
}
```

And alternative would be to revers the loop order, first iterate through all balls and for each ball check each pocket, once you find that is in a pocket continue the outer loop (skipping the check for the other pockets). In order to do this your `accelerateBall` function should return `true` or `false`, being `true` when the ball is close enough to the pocket and `false` otherwise.

I would re-write your iterations like this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < pockets.children.length; i++) {
    accelerateBallToPocket(cue, pockets.children[i], 60);
    if (cue.pocketing) break;
  }

  // Stumped...
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.children.length; i++) {
    // No need for the check here, each ball should have pocketing=false, set at the top of the update loop
    // This means, that balls.children[i].pocketing will always be false here
    for (var j = 0; j < pockets.children.length; j++) {
      accelerateBallToPocket(balls.children[i], pockets.children[j], 60);
      if (balls.children[i].pocketing) break; // stop checking the rest of the pockets for this ball
    }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work because I'm going by the proximity to the pocket, so the sprite stops updating if I set inPocket = true.  The "pockets" have attractive force but as yet I'm not getting rid of the balls if they are close to the pockets, just making them accelerate towards them and changing the scale.

Comment: Also I cannot use break or continue in the forEachAlive function. I get "illegal break" and continue warnings.

Comment: I've updated my question using the methods you describe. I got it halfway to work, need a bit more help, please.

Comment: The problem is with your second `if (balls.children[i].pocketing) continue;` . Continue only skips your current iteration, not stops the loop. Use `break;` instead. (this is the one in the inner loop): `if (balls.children[i].pocketing) break;`. Also, see my edit.